# Name of distance from center to side of rectangle

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there a special name for the distance from the center of a rectangle to a side?  I haven't done geometry in a while, but I thought there was an equivalent of a "radius" for regular polygons.

Comment: Half-length of a side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the word you want is [apothem](http://enwp.org/apothem). But that only applies to squares, not rectangles in general.

Or perhaps you want [inradius](http://enwp.org/inradius), although that's usually for triangles.

Comment: Apothem! I knew it was a vaguely funny-sounding word.